# How would I make a image scale with the browser or screen resolution with css

Tags: css, positioning, forum, mybb

I am working on a page for my mybb forum and I added some images and I want them to scale with the screen resolution so if I have a 17" it looks the same as someone with a 19" screen. Because right now the images just look all messed up. Here is the page that I am working on. http://crescentgaming.com/forums/test.php

Comment: Try looking in to CSS media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Why not just width 100%? That in combination with media queries to serve the closest resolution should do it

Comment: What image is it on the test? It's unclear what you mean by "the same" for the different screen sizes.

Comment: @ ArleyM I am talking about them all if you zoom in you will see that most of the images move instead of staying in place and just re sizing

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, use percents.

HTML

```
<img src="/folder/whatever.jpg">
```

CSS

```
img{
  width: 45%;
}
```

Of course, you could switch it to whatever percent you want. There is a more complicated way with JavaScript, but this usually works (for me).

Answer (score 0):

try the % instead of the px unit 
or use @media and specify dimensions for any resolution
[@media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

[CSS @media for standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

I hope that will help 
PS: under the @media you can specify changes only for certain elements, ID or classes so you don't have to redesign the hole page (as far as I know) so don't be shy to give it a try :)