# How would you make an image stay in place but it stays with the browser or screen resolution

Tags: css, positioning

I asked a question a couple days ago but I dont think I was clear enough so I will clear it up. First let me show you two images and you will see what my problem is. This is what it looks like for me http://puu.sh/2NrEi.jpg but for people with different screen resolutions or have their browser zoomed in they see this http://puu.sh/2NrED.jpg and I dont know how I would stop this from happening.

Here is some of my code. (I totally suck at css)

```
 <style>
    #div1 {
    position: absolute;
        left: 542px;
    top: 432px;
    }
    #div3 {
    position: absolute;
        left: 264px;
    top: 433px;
    }
    #div4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1045px;
    top: 432px;
    }
    #div5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 313px;
    top: 566px;
    }
    #divl {
    position: absolute;
        left: 542px;
    top: 460px;
    }
        </style>
```

Comment: Without some html/css code it will be hard to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: ya let me add some real quick

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I make a image scale with the browser or screen resolution with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369661/how-would-i-make-a-image-scale-with-the-browser-or-screen-resolution-with-css). You need to edit the existing question with reasons why the answers you received there didn't solve the problem. As you can see, otherwise you'll just get the exact same solutions again.

Comment: I figured out what my problem is I dont know any other way of positioning other then using pixels

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
<div class="main">
<div class="box size1">Div1 for rank information</div>
<div class="box size2">Div2 for center content</div>
<div class="box size1">Div3 for need help box</div>
</div>
```

css :-

```
.main
{
 width:100%;
}
.box 
{
 display:inline-block;
}
.size1 
{
 widht:20%;
}
.size2 
{
 widht:60%;
}
```

set width in percentage

Comment: or use `margin-...` for main div with pixel values and same ones for width of surrounders